# erro com password_verify()

Tags: php, hash, password

boa tarde estou com um problema na utilização do `password_verif()` ele nao esta verificando corretamente para efetuar o login, está caindo direto no `else` com a msg "senha incorreta". alguém poderia me ajudar?

funcoes:

```
private function compararSenha($hash){
    return password_verify($this->getSenha(), $hash);
}

private function findEmail($campo){
    $consulta = parent::select($campo, 'funcionario', 'WHERE email = ?', 's', array($this->getEmail()));
    $result = $consulta->fetch_object();

    if($consulta->num_rows > 0){
        if($campo == 'senha'){
            return $result->senha;
        }else if($campo == 'email'){
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

public function logar(){
    $msgResult = array();
    $resultSearchPass = $this->findEmail('senha');

    if($resultSearchPass){
        if($this->compararSenha($this->getSenha(), $resultSearchPass)){
            $consulta = parent::select('id', 'funcionario', 'WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?', 'ss', array($this->getEmail(), $this->getSenha()));
            $result = $consulta->fetch_object();

               if($consulta->num_rows > 0){
                    $_SESSION['idFuncionario'] = $result->id;
                    $_SESSION['logado'] = true;

                    $msgResult['tipo'] = 'success';
                    $msgResult['msg'] = "Login Efetuado com Sucesso!";
                    return json_encode($msgResult);
                }else{
                    $msgResult['tipo'] = 'error';
                    $msgResult['msg'] = 'Email ou Senha Incorretos!';
                    return json_encode($msgResult);
                }
            }else{
                $msgResult['tipo'] = 'error';
                $msgResult['msg'] = 'Senha Incorreta!';
                return json_encode($msgResult);
            }
        }else{
            $msgResult['tipo'] = 'error';
            $msgResult['msg'] = 'Email não Existe!';
            return json_encode($msgResult);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Você verificou se `$resultSearchPass` contém uma string válida e se ela foi criada pelo método [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: sim esta vindo normalmente do banco ja verifiquei. ele para de pegar nessa parte n me trazendo resultado nenhum `if($this->compararSenha($this->getSenha(), $resultSearchPass))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está passando os parâmetros errados para o seu método. Repare na assinatura do seu método:

```
private function compararSenha($hash){
    return password_verify($this->getSenha(), $hash);
}
```

Ela recebe apenas o *hash*, pois a senha é buscada no próprio objeto através do método `getSenha()`. Então este método só precisa receber a *hash* e nada mais.

Porém, no seu código você chama este método passando dois argumentos, a senha e o hash e sua função está utilizando a senha como hash, e descartando `$resultSearchPass`.

Para corrigir este problema basta trocar:

```
if ($this->compararSenha($this->getSenha(), $resultSearchPass)) {
    // ...
}
```

Por:

```
if ($this->compararSenha($resultSearchPass)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: uma duvida ex: vem do meu BD we321234232345dasd. suponha q isso seja 123 criptografado, no select quando for usar eu uso 123 ou o resultado do bd?

Comment: No select você só usa o email... Nunca pesquise por senha. Busque o email e depois use o `password_verify`

Comment: intendi obrigado